# Error reading Excel Interop Cell: Cannot convert mthod group 'ToString' to non-delegated type 'String'

Tags: c#, .net, excel, compiler-errors, vsto

Can anyone tell me what I a doing wrong with this code?  I am trying to read in a cell and assign the value to the String node1.

```
public void createEdgeListFromRange(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook)
{
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Time Series");
    Excel.Range range = ws.UsedRange;
    for (int row = 0; row < range.Rows.Count; row++ )
    {
        String node1 = ws.Cells["A", row].ToString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
ToString(); // missed brackets
```

because

`ToString()` is a method call, `ToString` (if it exists) is a property (or field) call.